# PHP pagination for unordered list

Tags: php, jquery

item1    item2  item3

I've three items arranged in this order,i've used unordered list to arrange the items in this order. I did n't find a pagination plug in for items arranged in unordered list ,How do i implement pagination for this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does not exactly work? what plugin do you want? What's the code you've written and fails?

Comment: It might help to follow this tutorial on pagination, and see if it helps you.
http://www.tyleringram.com/blog/basic-php-and-mysql-pagination-tutorial

Comment: @Kao:I'm looking for an jquery tutorial.

Comment: @PLB:I tried tablesorter plug in,tablesorter can be only implemented on table not on un ordered list.

Comment: May I suggest this one instead then:
http://www.jqueryrain.com/?piHSAiMw

But remember, if you choose to do pagination on client side, you might end up with a huge loading time due to the possibly massive amounts of data being drawn out on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/wesnolte/Pajinate for unordered list.